# CSS alternate floating of DIVs

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="messages">
    <div class="message">1</div>
    <div class="message">2</div>
    <div class="message">3</div>
    <div class="message">4</div>
    <div class="message">5</div>
    <div class="message">6</div>
    <div class="message">7</div>
    <div class="message">8</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is do some alternate float with them using odd/even nth-child selectors. However I want something a little more sophisticated. Instead of having each message node do a "clear", I want them to be able to stick close to the node on top of them. Is this possible through CSS only?

[image]

Edit:
There is no need to randomly assign heights for the boxes. Each of the boxes will have body of text inside of them (people's comments) which will make the heights variable for each one. I'm sorry if I failed to illustrate that here.

Comment: I believe you would need some variety of Javascript to make the random alternating heights, but let me see what I can do.

Comment: You need JS for this—something like Masonry or Isotope. BTW, don't use the same class on every element. You can target all those `message` divs with `.messages > div`.

Comment: Some people are trigger happy with that *close* button. I see not reason this question is invalid.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it only using CSS. But there are good jQuery plugins out there like jQuery wookmark and jQuery Masonry that will do this neatly. Of course if that's a option for you.

Comment: i believe the only way to do this with css and html only is to actually attribute fixed/relative height-widths to each of the 'cells'. It certainly would look far more complex than just a series of `div`s in a parent container `div` in order to pull it off though.. something similar to what they are using on http://news.net/ to do the layout grid

Comment: This layout is possible using only CSS thanks to flexbox: http://demosthenes.info/blog/844/Easy-Masonry-Layout-With-Flexbox

Comment: @SteveSanders yeah as long as you don't need to support IE9

Comment: @SteveSanders That layout is filling the first column before putting anything into the other ones. It's not what the OP wanted. Notice the LTR direction in his example.

Comment: I think something like Masonry is in the path I was going for. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am by no means a CSS guru, but in messing around with some filler text, I was able to get this.

the `clear:` statements are made because without them you sometimes get "even numbers" appearing on the "odd numbers" side.

Odds are someone way better will give you a much better answer.

So to answer your original question, what you want is "sort of" possible with CSS. I can't figure out why the 7 div starts where it does.

```css
.alt,
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.alt div:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
.alt div:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.alt div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="alt">
  <div>1 lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  <div>2 lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  <div>3 lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  <div>4 lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor.
    lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor.lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem
    ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  <div>5lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  <div>6lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  <div>7lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem
    ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor.lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum
    dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  <div>8 lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor. lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the annoying placement of the 7th div?

Comment: Can't say I did. It either starts where it does in the example or it clumps up onto the wrong side. I'm assuming it's something to do with the alternating clears, but without them it doesn't work.

Comment: I found the reason! http://w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position - point 5: "_The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the source document._" So the top of box 7 cannot be higher than the top of box 6.

Comment: Ah, then we'd need js to accomplish it fully.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using floats:

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2u0Ldxeh/)

---

I just now noticed that you wanted to have the heights rely on the contents. I know of no other way to accomplish this then to set the heights of the boxes based on the largest one using jQuery/JS.

The floating structure relies on the heights of the boxes being very precise, so boxes #1 and #4, #2 and #3, #5 and #8, and #6 and #7 must all have the same height or it simply will not work.

---

Otherwise, here you go, with static heights:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="message"></div>
    <div class="message"></div>
    <div class="message"></div>
    <div class="message"></div>
    <div class="message short"></div>
    <div class="message short"></div>
    <div class="message short"></div>
    <div class="message short"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.container
{
    width: 600px;
    font-size: 0;
}

div.message {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    background: #ccc;
    
    margin: 5px;
}

div.message.short
{
    height: 200px;
}

div.message:nth-child(4n-3),
div.message:nth-child(4n)
{
    float: left;
}

div.message:nth-child(4n-1)
{
    float: right;
}

div.message:nth-child(4n-2),
div.message:nth-child(4n)
{
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with a combination of CSS and Javascript, like Masonry or Isotope; but most likely cannot be done with CSS3. Maybe when CSS4 comes out it will be possible, but that's a long way off.

Alternatively, what I would do is pre-design what I want and then define separate classes to the divs. FOr example, in the picture, 2 and 3 would be the same class, and 4, 6, and 7 would be the same class; and then use CSS positioning, floats, margin, and padding to define appropriately.

If you want something dynamic, you can't with CSS alone; but if you know what you want it to look like, you can use CSS by defining separate classes to the different divs.

p.s. you can use css child to define sets of classes, but it's still doing the same thing, it's not completely dynamic as you'll need to know what you want it to look like first.